# How can I place $content in search results instead of $snippet?

Tags: search

I'm using the [Link module](https://www.drupal.org/project/link) to display a field that links to an external site. `$snippet` places this link (along with other fields) in a paragraph. The fields have no separation and the link doesn't work. I'd like to place $content in search-result.tpl to remedy this but everything I've tried has given me an error.

Someone mentions `$result` [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search-result.tpl.php/7) which may be what I need.

I tried `<?php print $result['field_lipsum']; ?>` but it gives me `Notice: Undefined index: field_lipsum in include() . . .`

How can I place $content in search results instead of $snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Define [*yourtheme*_preprocess_search_result](http://template_preprocess_search_result) in your theme's **template.php** file. Do something like this:

`function yourtheme_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
  //$variables['result']['node'] should contain the entire node object
  $variables['content'] = $variables['result']['node']->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
}`

You should be able to use the variable **$content** inside **search-result.tpl.php** now.

Comment: Do I need to place function in front of that? I already have a yourtheme_preprocess_search_result. can I do yourtheme_preprocess_search_results? I tried adding it to that function but it gave me the error Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$body in podliberty_preprocess_search_result()

Comment: Yes, function needs to be in front of the function name.

Comment: Okay I did it in a new function. (preprocess_search_resultS) then put  <?php 
 hide($content['comments']);
 hide($content['links']);
 print render($content);
 ?> in search-result.tpl but it doesn't show up

Comment: What do you mean by should contain the entire node object?

Comment: In the above example, it should just be setting a variable $content with the entire node content. You should be able to use `print $content;` to output it.

Comment: print $content gives me Notice: Undefined variable: content in include() (line 98,  print render($content) gives no error but no content

Comment: It might be easier for you to ignore yourtheme_preprocess_search_result. Use `print $result['node']->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];` inside search-result.tpl.php

Comment: That gives Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$body in include() is value supposed to be the field?

Comment: Hmm well you can try `print '<pre>'.print_r($result['node'], true).'</pre>';` That should give a print out of what's contained inside $result['node'].

Comment: Hmm that does work but it gives a massive list of code. The two fields I want are at the bottom though and the link does work. Any way to just get the fields with that?

Comment: Yup, you can print out something like `print $result['node']-> field_lipsum[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']` if field_lipsum is the name of your custom field. 

I believe the link module uses the 'url' element (instead of 'value') but I don't remember for sure.

Comment: Getting close I think! It doesn't output the title for value, field_lipsum, which is "Lipsum: null", inline. It just does "null". And for field_download, the link, it does the URL in plain text. I have the link set to static title "Download" which goes to the link.

Comment: I'll leave it to you to experiment around then. All the data you need is in $result['node'] (the node object includes all data about your content). You might find the [devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) useful for understanding the structure of a node object.

Comment: I just realized I can wrap it in an anchor and just put the title in front of the other field. Duh. I appreciate the help Shawn.